# All Excel options are greyed out

Tags: excel

I found an Excel document on reddit that I am attempting to edit to suit my needs. I am having issues with it and went in to the options to change some settings. Everything is greyed out and cannot be changed. I have checked the file to make sure that it is not read only. I am as admin on the computer and, as far as I can see, have permissions for the file. I have tried closing and reopening, as well as restarting the computer. Is there something obvious that I am missing? Or does anyone know how I can fix this so that I can keep editing the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All boxes are grayed out and look inaccessible, however they are still clickable and any changes made stay. I was punked by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

It probably means that you have grouped two or more sheets
...Be very careful. Any change to one sheet impacts all grouped sheets (deleting rows, entering values, etc)

To UNgroup the sheets:
• Click the tab of any sheet that is not part of the group
or
• Right-Click one of the grouped sheet tabs...Select: Ungroup

Once the last sheet is Ungrouped...the [GROUP] label will disappear.

To Group sheets...
• Hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key when selecting tabs

This answer is cited from 
Ron Coderre

Answer (score 0):

Answer sourced [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/grayedout.htm)

> Probably have sheet protection turned on which will turn off several options
>
> Make sure you are not in Edit mode by hitting Esc (Escape key), as edit mode >will gray out a lot of menu options -- notably most Edit options (except cut >& paste).  Will grayout Options under Toolbar; many options under Data and >under Window.
>
> Tools -> Protection -> Unprotect Worksheet

Comment: Posted the first google result you could find, huh? The Tools menu disappeared with Excel 2007, ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows the general options for working with Excel, independent of any files. If you cannot edit a workbook, check if the workbook structure or the sheets are protected. Review ribbon > Unprotect.

Comment: Is there a way to make the general Excel options changeable? I need to change some things in there and am not sure why they are greyed out in the first place.

Comment: I do notice that the options are greyed out in Word as well. I have Office 2016, as downloaded from my college Office 365 exchange email. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: Have you activated your copy of Office? If you can't do anything with it, then the license may have expired. Go to File > Account and study what you see there. Maybe you just need to go online and authenticate with your college ID again, so Office knows it's a legit install. Or maybe your license has expired (for eg if you no longer attend the college), in which case you can only read files, not change anything.

Comment: I am still able to edit files with no issue, but everything in the options is greyed out. It's odd.

Comment: What do you see on your accounts screen?

Comment: My user and subscription information. When I click "manage account" it has me log in to the exchange, where it shows that I have an active subscription to Office 2016.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Everything LOOKS greyed out, but are you sure you cannot change the settings? Excel these days is very grey on white.

Answer (score 0):

I have this a lot, the problem is the show the preview pane where the file is saved. If the preview pane is showing the file, XL thinks its open so will not allow changes from menus. Click on another file or close the preview pane and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the same issue occured, on all sheets, in a single workbook.  The following was performed:

- closed and opened workbook (handles the "in edit mode" possibility; plus)
- Ensured selection of a single worksheet (not previously suggested)
- clicked Unprotect in File -> Info -> (section Protect Workbook)
- Edited a worksheet and saved the workbook (proved no Excel or File
  protections)

Nothing helped.  This got around the issue.

- Closed workbook
- Made copy of workbook
- Changed name of original (the one having issues
- Opened the workbook copy (with original name)

Neither the cause of the issue nor the 'simple' correction has been discovered but all is now well.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you just need to **unhide the worksheet**, which was hidden by someone or due to a misconfiguration.

[image]

If it was hidden, it will open up a dialog window asking to confirm the unhide action.
This was tested here in Excel 2010 and Excel 365.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The file was in SHARED mode. I didn't realize that. I clicked the SHARE WORKBOOK, and unchecked the box that said "allow changes by more than one user.." and all my menu items came back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed by unchecking the option of share workbook (allow changes by more than one user at the same time... )

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path :
File / Options / General
then select option "Optimize for compatibility".